# How to represent term more concisely

Tags: summation, logarithms, factoring

I have the following term : $\log_2 (3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot...\cdot(n -1 - ((n - 1)$ mod $3))$.

Unfortunately, i don't know how to reduce this form. I think that the input term is equal to  $\log (\frac{n}{3}!)$, but i'm not convinced in it. So what is the concise representation of the input term?

Comment: Did you actually mean that inner $\log$ there?

Comment: A, yes it was my mistake! Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Well, it looks like $\log_2(n!\cdot3^n)$.

Comment: If so, then it goes $\log_2 n! + \log_2 3^n = \log_2 1 + \log_2 2 + ...+ \log_2 n + n\cdot\log_2 3$. And i'm not sure that this sum is equal to initial value.

Comment: Really? Give it a try, it looks alright to me in Python.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You were right. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome :)